# Website - Take a photo with html from cam of my phone over png

Tags: html, mobile, camera

I do not know to do a photo with the cam of my phone. I make to website to take a photo with an image over the webcam image, to use to add a tittle or another thing.

The idea is this, it do a photo with over png image. The user will see the title of the png image and he will be in back.

Could you help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your code, etc.? It's bit difficult to understand the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take a picture with built-in camera of your device, you can use the camera API provided in HTML5. Take a look at [this tutorial](https://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera). To add text, images or whatever you might think of on top of that image, you should probably look at PHP and ImageMagick.